# Anguar 7 used NGRX and problem with e2e test with protactor

Tags: angular, protractor, ngrx-store

i have some problem with my app..

office.components.html

```
<div class="form-group" [class.text-danger]="form.name?.invalid && (form.name?.dirty || form.name?.touched)">
   <label for="name">OFFICE</label>
   <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" value="" formControlName="name"
     [class.border-danger]="form.name?.invalid && (form.name?.dirty || form.name?.touched)" required />
   <div *ngIf="form.name?.errors && (form.name?.dirty || form.name?.touched)">
     <div [hidden]="!form.name?.errors.required">Office required</div>
     <div [hidden]="!form.name?.errors.minlength">Office is too short</div>
     <div [hidden]="!form.name?.errors.maxlength">Office is too long</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

office.components.ts

```
officeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(250)]],
});


ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new FetchOffice());
    this.officeSubscription = this.store.select('office').subscribe((officeState: OfficeState) => {
        this.officeForm.patchValue(officeState);
    });
}
```

office.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('check error message for required input', () => {
    const formNameElement = element(by.name('name'));
    formNameElement.clear();
    formNameElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    const formNameElementParent = formNameElement.element(by.xpath('..'));
    const formNameElementError = formNameElementParent.element(by.xpath('div/div[1]'));
    expect(formNameElementError.getText()).toEqual('Office required');
});
```

error Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, div/div[1])

but the test below works

```
it('check error message for required input', () => {
    const formNameElement = element(by.name('name'));
    formNameElement.clear();
    formNameElement.sendKeys('1');
    formNameElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    const formNameElementParent = formNameElement.element(by.xpath('..'));
    const formNameElementError = formNameElementParent.element(by.xpath('div/div[2]'));
    expect(formNameElementError.getText()).toEqual('Office is too short');
});
```

when i removes

```
this.officeForm.patchValue(officeState);
```

all test works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I had to replace:

```
formNameElement.clear();
formNameElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
```

on

```
formNameElement.clear();
formNameElement.sendKeys('1');
formNameElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
formNameElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

When chaining xpath locators you need to prefix your locator with the `./` or `.//` syntax. This indicates that you want to find a element relative to the one you are chaining onto.

It appears though your whole code could be simplified by using [xpath axes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_axes.htm) to identify those relative elements.

For instance, instead of you original

```
const formNameElement = element(by.name('name'));
const formNameElementParent = formNameElement.element(by.xpath('..'));
const formNameElementError = formNameElementParent.element(by.xpath('div/div[2]'));
```

You could achieve the same using the parent axes **(updated with following-sibling)**

```
const formNameElement = element(by.name('name'));
const formNameElementError = element(by.xpath('//[@name="name]/following-sibling::div[1]'));
```

Comment: In my opinion problem is with when i try clear formNameElement. When i test it i see that is empty but i do not know why form.name.errors is null...

Comment: Could you post the HTML as rendered in the DOM as opposed to the angular html template?

Comment: based on that code I think you should be using `formNameElement = element(by.id('name'))` and, assuming that works, `formNameElementError = formNameElement.element(by.xpath("./following-sibling::div/div[2]")`. `id` is usually the best locator to use if it is present

Comment: Theoretically when i clean formNameElement they should add div with errors, but this not working to protactor

Comment: Ah I see. I have seen similar behavior recently and it is likely because `.clear` will not trigger a dom refresh and therefore your site will not realize the field has been cleared. You could try adding a `.click` in that field afterwards or what i did was was send a keystroke of a character and then a backspace (using `protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE`)

Comment: I added `formNameElement.clear().then(function () {
                        formNameElement.click();
                        formNameElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
                    });` and it still does not work

Comment: I found the solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529795/5260590 Thanks for help :)

Comment: Cool glad to hear it, that was actually the approach I was referring to when I said 'send a keystroke of a character and then a backspace' but can see that may not have been clear and an example would of helped. Glad you got it anyway